# gRPC-Gateway does not generate resiterwith http endpoint method

Tags: go, grpc

I'm trying to use `https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway` to enable my go grpc methods to be available to be called by http as well.  To that end I'm using the module `https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway`.  However when I generate the proto files using protoc I dont see a method `Register*FromEndpoint` as shown in the example.  This is what my .proto file looks like

```
syntax = "proto3";

package health;

option go_package = "github.com/user/app/api/health";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";

service Health {
    rpc Ping (HealthRequest) returns (HealthReply) {
      option (google.api.http) = {
        get: "/ping"
      };
    }
  }
  
  // The request message containing the user's name
  message HealthRequest {    
  }
  
  // The response message containing the greetings
  message HealthReply {
    string message = 1;
  }
```

This is what my protoc command looks like

```
protoc --go_out=api/proto/ --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --go-grpc_out=./api/proto --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --proto_path=internal/api \
    --proto_path=third_party \
    ./internal/api/health/health.proto
```

The generation works fine without any errors, but the generated `health_grpc.pb.go` file does not have the equivalent `RegisterYourServiceHandlerFromEndpoint` method as shown in the example here `https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway`

Comment: Your `protoc` options don't appear to include the flags to trigger gRPC-Gateway code generation e.g. `--grpc-gateway_opt logtostderr=true --grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative` (this is covered at the top of step 4 in the [usage instructions](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway#usage)).

Answer (score 0):

As document of grpc-gateway saied, I suggested you to use [buf](https://buf.build/) rather than protoc, and it more easy and friendly.

You can reference the document of [grpc-gateway#usage](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway#usage)

```yaml
version: v1beta1
plugins:
  - name: go
    out: gen/go
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative
  - name: go-grpc
    out: gen/go
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative
  - name: grpc-gateway
    out: gen/go
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative
      - generate_unbound_methods=true
```

And if you still want use protoc, you need add `--grpc-gateway_opt` param:

```sh
protoc -I . --grpc-gateway_out ./gen/go \
    --grpc-gateway_opt logtostderr=true \
    --grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative \
    --grpc-gateway_opt generate_unbound_methods=true \
    your/service/v1/your_service.proto
```

Comment: thanks for this, I added these flags and then I get the following error `Unknown flag: --grpc-gateway_opt`.  I have run go install and installed

    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway \
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2 \
    google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go \
    google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc

Comment: @tmpdev Yep, use protoc has wired issues, just use buf, it works well.

Comment: I finally got it working with the following 

 protoc \
  --grpc-gateway_out ./api/proto \
     --grpc-gateway_opt logtostderr=true \
     --grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative \
  --go_out=api/proto \
  --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
  --go-grpc_out=./api/proto \
  --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
  --proto_path=internal/api \
  --proto_path=third_party \
     --grpc-gateway_opt generate_unbound_methods=true \
     ./internal/api/health/health.proto

Answer (score 0):

For generating the stubs, we can use either `protoc` or `buf`. `protoc` is the more classic generation experience used widely in the industry. Still, it has a pretty steep learning curve. `buf` is a newer tool built with user experience and speed in mind. It also offers linting and breaking change detection, and something `protoc` doesn’t provide.

You can read more about `buf` here: https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/tutorials/generating_stubs/using_buf/.